# Import Data from Excel to Sql Server 2008 #2

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, oledb

```
string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/"), FileUpload1.FileName);
//Save File as Temp then you can delete it if you want 
FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);


string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);

// Create Connection to Excel Workbook 
using (OleDbConnection connection =
             new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
            ("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);

    connection.Open();

    // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet 
    using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {

        // SQL Server Connection String 
        string sqlConnectionString = @conn;

        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server 
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                   new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName ="Table1";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            Label1.Text = "The Client data has been exported successfully from Excel to SQL";
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to import data from excel to SQL Server, it works fine till I am not passing date but now I want to pass the date to SQL Server it provides error as datatype not matches.

Anyone has logic or please suggest me what can I do to ..

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` you read from excel is OLE Automation date and you have to convert it to c# `DateTime` before you insert in to sql server. It would be double value for date when you read from excel. You can use [DateTime.FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert the double value to `DateTime`. You can use [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this method allows you to pass the datatable. You can change the date in datatable in require format and use it to save bulk data in sql server. You can import excel data to datatable, this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/376355/import-MS-Excel-to-datatable) will help you.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(stringVariableContainingDateTime));
```

Comment: how can i convert it as i am importing data in bulk ..
Is there anything so that i can import it to an datatable and then to an sql server so that we can check each data from datatable and convert it

Comment: Hello as i am new to asp i am not aware but i checked it .. i used datareader nd i am executing datareader to insert my value and if i am writing to datatable then how can i execute it datatable values to insert my data ??
n thanx for your reply

Comment: You can import excel data to datatable, http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/376355/import-MS-Excel-to-datatable

Comment: yeh thanx vl try to implement if i gt vl let u know thanx

Answer (score 0):

Might be the column in the Excel Sheet is not in a valid date format.

Change it to Date Type.

```
Select the Column in the Excel Sheet -> Right Click -> Format Cells ->
Number Tab -> Select Date -> Choose your desired Type -> Ok
```

Then you try to Import...

Comment: I had tried this but not working...

did you try this anytime ??

Answer (score 0):

It works i tried to convert it in datatble den change datatype and then insert

```
 string sqlConnectionString = @conn;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();

                objAdapter1.Fill(dt);

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[0][5].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        DateTime dt1 = cf.texttodb(dt.Rows[0][5].ToString());
                        dt.Rows[i][5] = dt1;
                    }}
 using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                               new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Tablename";
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    Label1.Text = "The Client data has been exported successfully from Excel to SQL";
                }
```

in this i had created a function txtdob which converts my string to datetime format
Thank you 
i tried it workes if u feel so mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Using  Web form  ..

using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class YourPageName : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string excelFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + FileUpload1.FileName;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelFilePath);
            ImportDataFromExcel(excelFilePath);
        }
    }

    public void ImportDataFromExcel(string excelFilePath)
    {`enter code here`
        string ssqltable = TextBox1.Text;
        string myexceldataquery = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
        try
        {
            string sexcelconnectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;'";
            string ssqlconnectionstring = "Data Source=95.217.196.125;Initial Catalog=Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Dup(e)0@98!";
            string sclearsql = "DELETE FROM " + ssqltable;

            using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring))
            {
                sqlconn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn))
                {
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            using (OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring))
            {
                oledbconn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn))
                {
                    using (OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring))
                        {
                            sqlconn.Open();

                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlconn))
                            {
                                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
                                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Label1.Text = "File imported into SQL Server successfully.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?